# Batch: How to replace % sign within a variable?

Tags: batch-file, escaping, invalid-characters

I'm trying to rename my files to remove any characters that cause problems in scripts. This works well for ampersand and exclamation point but when the file has the percent sign it doesn't show up in the variable to begin with. How do I pass files with special characters via for loop?

```
for %%v in (*) do call :validate "%%v"
exit /b

:validate
set "original=%~nx1"
set "newtitle=%original:!=%"
set "newtitle=%newtitle:&=and%"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "newtitle=!newtitle:%%= percent!"
if not "%newtitle%"=="%original%" ren %1 "%newtitle%"
```

Comment: Have you ever seen this syntax? `Set "Var=String"`

Comment: Yes, why? It doesn't help.

Comment: Still no. With %% the resulting variable is empty, with ^% it remains unchanged.

Comment: @Johnny, I would advise you to use it as good practice.

Comment: Try enabling delayed expansion with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, then use `set foo=!bar:%%= percent!`.

Comment: Compo is referring to the *quoted* syntax, which is the safest way to define variables, even with white-spaces and special characters...

Comment: Changing relevant parts of the question is a bad idea. The answer refers now to another problem than your current problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the line `for %%v in (*) do call :validate "%%v", because the`call` starts the parser a second time and there all percents are evaluated a second time.

You should save the value into a variable and access these variable in your function instead.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%v in (*) do (
  set "filename=%%~v"
  call :validate
)
exit /b

:validate
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "original=!filename!"
set "newtitle=%original:!=exclam%"
set "newtitle=!newtitle:&=and!"
set "newtitle=!newtitle:%=percent!"
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I am learning good stuff right here. BTW what are the implications if I like to build the part inside the parenthesis into a single line? Is it merely frowned upon?

Comment: @JohnnyRogers Do you mean `set "filename=%%~v" & call :validate`?  It works, but it has no advantage. And it's harder to read

Comment: OK, roger that.

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```cmd
set "newfilename=%filename:&=and%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "newfilename=!newfilename:%%= percent!"

endlocal
```

The `%`-sign must be escaped by doubling it in a batch file.

Note that the variable is no longer available beyond the `endlocal` command.

I used the quoted syntax, which is the safest way to define variables, even with white-spaces and special characters.